# How can I determine the route of the application through deep linking based on the link

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-navigation-v6

This is my code
`‍App.js‍` :

```
function App() {
  const getInitialURL = async () => {
    const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();

    console.log('This is url',url)

    if (url !== null) {
      return url;
    }

    return undefined
  }
  const deepLinking = {
    prefixes: ['https://www.example.com','https://*.example.com','http://www.example.com','app://'],
    config: {
      initialRouteName:'HOME',
      screens: {
        HOME: 'home',
        LIVE: 'live/:uuid',
        TAGList: 'tag/:enVal'
      }
    },
    getInitialURL
  }
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={deepLinking}>
      <stack.Navigator 
      initialRouteName={'SPLASH'} 
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <stack.Screen name = "SPLASH" component={Splash}/> 
        <stack.Screen name = 'HOME' component = {Home}/>
        <stack.Screen name = "LIVE" component={LiveOne}/>
        <stack.Screen name = "TAGList" component={TagList}/>
      </stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`android/app/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="app" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

So, with this code, when I click on the link started by `example.com`, the app opens `HOME screen`, but I need for example, when the `example.com` is clicked, the `HOME screen` opens, and when the `example.com/m/`**`uuid`** is clicked, the app opens and change the screen to the `LIVE screen` and send the **`uuid`** to the same screen

For now, I can only open `LIVE screen` app with same params with this command :
 `npx uri-scheme open "app://LIVE/3a35ed925895A26" --android`
I need when click on the `example.com/m/3a35ed925895A26` app opened `LIVE screen` with `3a35ed925895A26` params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution myself

1- I had to make changes in the code in order to be able to access the app both through app:// and through various link models (with http without http - with https without https - with www without www).

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file :

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

//for app://
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="app" />
</intent-filter>

//for links
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

2- And deep linking prefixes :

```
  prefixes: [
      'https://www.example.com',
      'http://www.example.com',
      'https://*.example.com',
      'http://example.com',
      'https://example.com',
      'app://'
    ]
```

3- Now for example my link is something like this : `www.example.com/m/876c875dDfV3`, In order to be able to access the route `/m` through deep link, I need to define its route in screens as `m/:uuid`.
`/m` is route in my links, And `:uuid` is my params to this route, You can use your params or you're link structure.

```
    config: {
      initialRouteName:'home',
      screens: {
        HOME: 'home',
        LIVE: 'm/:uuid',
        TAGList: 'tag/:enVal'
      }
    }
```